Highlighted Image portion on top of image is not sticky when change the device resolution
I am creating one html page where i have one image in this page where i need to highlight the specific portion of image when i hover on specific part of image. I used below code to highlight the image marker on the image using below code:


.container {
    position:relative;
    height:455px;
    width:606px;
}
.grid{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
 grid-auto-rows: max-content;
 height: 100%;
 position:relative;
}

.overflow-auto {
    overflow: auto;
}
.grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.w-full {
    width: 100%;
}
.overflow-y-auto {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.h-full {
    height: 100%;
}

.auto-rows-max {
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}
.bg-surface-default {
    background-color: var(--surface-default);
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.\@container {
    container-type: inline-size;
}
.h-fit {
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}
img, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
img, svg, video, canvas, audio, iframe, embed, object {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
<div id="topic-details" class="w-full grow overflow-auto">
  <div class="h-full overflow-y-auto">
    <div
      class="relative grid h-full auto-rows-max md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3"
    >
      <div
        class="gap-4 bg-surface-default px-4 py-10 md:px-8 lg:px-12 flex flex-col py-3 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1"
      >
        <div class="header">
          <i></i>
          <h3
            class="text-[22px] font-normal text-content-bodytext md:text-content-title"
          >
            <span>Hello</span>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="relative @container">
          <div class="flex h-16 items-center gap-2">
            <div
              class="flex w-auto items-center gap-4 overflow-hidden h-4 w-11 shrink-0"
            >
              <div
                class="flex overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-surface-neutral-accented h-4 w-11"
              >
                <span
                  class="w-full"
                  style="
                    background: linear-gradient(
                      to right,
                      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
                    );
                  "
                ></span>
              </div>
              <span class="flex text-center text-content-default text-lg"
                >⚠️</span
              >
            </div>
            <div class="w-50">
              <span
                class="font-sans text-lg font-normal not-italic text-content-bodytext"
                >Another sample</span
              >
            </div>
            <label
              class="bg-diagnostic-sensor-gray-1-a h-6 w-6 shrink-0 cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-full border border-content-interactive-active stroke-outline-focus stroke-[1px] text-center text-base lg:hover:bg-button-surface-default-default bg-content-interactive-active text-surface-default"
              >?</label
            >
          </div>
          <div class="flex h-16 items-center gap-2">
            <div
              class="flex w-auto items-center gap-4 overflow-hidden h-4 w-11 shrink-0"
            >
              <div
                class="flex overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-surface-neutral-accented h-4 w-11"
              >
                <span
                  class="w-full"
                  style="
                    background: linear-gradient(
                      to right,
                      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
                    );
                  "
                ></span>
              </div>
              <span class="flex text-center text-content-default text-lg"
                >⚠️</span
              >
            </div>
            <div class="w-50">
              <span class="text-lg font-normal not-italic text-content-bodytext"
                >Another sample</span
              >
            </div>
            <label
              class="bg-diagnostic-sensor-gray-1-a h-6 w-6 shrink-0 cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-full border border-content-interactive-active stroke-outline-focus stroke-[1px] text-center text-base lg:hover:bg-button-surface-default-default"
              >?</label
            >
          </div>
          <div class="w-68 lg:w-90 pt-1">
            <span class="text-wrap pt-6 text-content-subdued"
              >Another sample Another sample</span
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="gap-4 bg-surface-default px-4 py-10 md:px-8 lg:px-12 relative h-[625px] py-3 md:col-span-2 md:h-[460px] lg:p-10 lg:px-4 lg:pb-6 lg:pt-9"
      >
        <div class="relative @container">
          <img
            alt="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQj5gTMDYtXjIPJ-RKel262ZywPjbjEVkRZZL1kM8Z1fWY-uTHvqxopMEjw2MxtJSqKgz8&usqp=CAU"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQj5gTMDYtXjIPJ-RKel262ZywPjbjEVkRZZL1kM8Z1fWY-uTHvqxopMEjw2MxtJSqKgz8&usqp=CAUg"
            class="absolute h-fit"
          />
          <div
            style="
              position: absolute;
              pointer-events: none;
              border-radius: 50%;
              width: 40px;
              height: 40px;
              overflow: hidden;
              border: 3px solid rgb(0, 116, 240);
              background-image: url(&quothttps://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQj5gTMDYtXjIPJ-RKel262ZywPjbjEVkRZZL1kM8Z1fWY-uTHvqxopMEjw2MxtJSqKgz8&usqp=CAU&quot;);
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              transition:
                top 0.3s,
                left 0.3s;
              top: 47px;
              left: 175px;
              background-position: -780px -375px;
              background-size: 1405px;
            "
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



You can find the same fiddle link here
I used it's container position to relative and the image and marker image position absolute, But the image marker position get change when change the device resolution.
It should be sticky on the same location when device resolution will get change.
Need help.
